# How can i retrieve "Height" from google fit api without setting time range?

Tags: android, google-fit

Below is code snippet what i use presently

```
        DataReadRequest readHeightRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

Which works fine, and returns height information for that particular time range.

What if i don't want to set the time range? I tried commenting ".setTimeRange" line, but ended up in giving exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid limit 0 is specified".

Here startTime is almost impossible to predict, since it is not possible to predict when the user inserted the Height details to Google Fit. How to deal with this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

To read the latest entry for height (or weight etc) use the [setLimit](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/DataReadRequest.Builder.html#setLimit(int)) method and set the startTime to the beginning of time (1):

```
long startTime = 1;
DataReadRequest readHeightRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .setLimit(1)
        .build();
```

> **public DataReadRequest.Builder setLimit (int limit)**
>
> Limits results to the latest limit data points. This parameter is
>   ignored for aggregated queries. By default there is no limit. This
>   method is useful to reduce the amount of sent data as well as to
>   support scenarios like requesting the current (limit == 1 to get the
>   latest value) weight or height.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the start time. According to the
[DataType TYPE_HEIGHT documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_HEIGHT):

> Because the recorded height is instantaneous, the start time should not be set.

Comment: That's sad. Here startTime is almost impossible to predict, since it is not possible to predict when the user inserted the Height details to Google Fit. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: I edited my answer. Even though the read requests require a time range, specifically for height start time should not be set. Try setting only the end time.

Comment: You know how the request should be then?